# Second display on HDMI doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, display, hdmi

I have a laptop **Lenovo IdeaPad-320-15ABR** with AMD graphics card running ubuntu 20.04.

The second display doesn't show anything, even after I enabled Wayland and run on Wayland

`echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE output`s `wayland`

If I run `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto` I get this message

```
warning: output HDMI-1 not found; ignoring
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just troubleshooted this exact problem. I too have an AMD card. Try installing Ubuntu 20.10. I thought 20.04 was the latest, but its not. Apparently 20.10 has more support for AMD https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.10/

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work. Any other ideas?